# Bazel giving errors with @rules_python

Tags: python, bazel

I am trying to follow through the tutorials on https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/master/examples/pip_install/

I have my own custom project with the following structure

```
root
   WORKSPACE
   requirements.txt
   scripts
       BUILD
       test.py
```

My workspace file looks like this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.2.0/rules_python-0.2.0.tar.gz",
    sha256 = "778197e26c5fbeb07ac2a2c5ae405b30f6cb7ad1f5510ea6fdac03bded96cc6f",
)

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_install")

pip_install(
    requirements = "//:requirements.txt",
)
```

and my BUILD file as such

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@pip//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_binary", "py_test")
load("@rules_python//python/pip_install:requirements.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

py_binary(
    name = "Test",
    srcs = [ "Test.py" ],
    # deps = [
    #     requirement("numpy"),
    # ],
)
```

However, when i run `bazel run //scripts:Test`

it fails with

`ERROR: Skipping '//scripts:Test': error loading package 'scripts': cannot load '@rules_python//python/pip_install:requirements.bzl': no such file`

I have no idea what i am doing wrong